# Incorrect Multiplication

Tags: java, math, multiplication

I am trying to solve this one particular problem involving basic math. My algorithm works for every other test cases and thus i know its correct. But for one particular input in one of the test cases, the result is wrong. I checked the values by printing them and values are:

```
a = 1000000000 and b = 999999999
```

When I do

```
System.out.print(a*b);
```

it returns 1808348672.

I have tried doing this:

```
long ans = (long)a*b;
System.out.print(ans);
```

It still returns 1808348672

Comment: That’s a bad duplicate — it doesn’t answer this question. The real issue is that the problem isn’t reproducible because OP’s code works.

Comment: @Mureinik Please leave it alone. The whole problem here is that there was *no* relevant [tag:casting]. Just a non-reproducible problem.

Answer (score 5):

> I have tried doing this:
>
> ```
> long ans = (long)a*b;
> System.out.print(ans);
> ```
>
> It still returns 1808348672

No, it doesn’t:

```
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1000000000;
        int b = 999999999;
        long ans = (long)a*b;
        System.out.print(ans);
    }
}
```

```sh
javac foo.java && java Foo
999999999000000000
```

What you probably tried instead is

```
long ans = (long) (a*b);
```

This will *first* perform integer multiplication, and then cast the *result* to `long`. That doesn’t work since the integer multiplication overflows before your cast happens.

Comment: My bad. I used int type for ans and tried to store long in an int variable.

Comment: @JaideepKular That would not have compiled without yet another cast.

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are `int`s, so their multiplication will also be an `int`, which overflows before being promoted to a `long` by the explicit cast.

You can define them as `long`s or cast them individually to `long`s **before** performing the multiplication.

Comment: It worked by casting each of them individually. But why do I need to cast them individually? I tried to cast the whole operation and it didn't work.

Comment: @JaideepKular casting the result is too late - multiplying two `int` will result in an `int`, which already overflows before you cast it. If you cast them individually, you'd be multiplying two `long`s, which result in a `long` that can accommodate the result without overflowing.